# Find duplicates and reduce them to unique rows in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a delimited array like this below:

```
BKR:::10-03:::2
BKR:::10-04:::1
BKR:::10-04:::4
BKR:::10-07:::7
BKR:::10-08:::6
BKR:::10-10:::2
BKR:::10-10:::2
BKR:::10-11:::3
CR:::10-04:::4
CR:::10-07:::2
CR:::10-07:::2
EL:::10-02:::4
EL:::10-03:::1
EL:::10-04:::2
EL:::10-07:::1
EL:::10-07:::2
EL:::10-07:::2
EL:::10-07:::2
EL:::10-07:::4
RL:::10-08:::6
```

I would like to reduce the rows where there are duplicate second columns (for e.g.,rows 2 and 3 have BKR 10-4, so, I want one row BKR 10-4 but add up 1 + 4 and show as BKR:::10-04:::5)

Finally, the array should like this:

```
BKR:::10-03:::2
BKR:::10-04:::5 
BKR:::10-07:::7
BKR:::10-08:::6
BKR:::10-10:::4 
BKR:::10-11:::3
CR:::10-04:::4
CR:::10-07:::4 
EL:::10-02:::4
EL:::10-03:::1
EL:::10-04:::2
EL:::10-07:::11 
RL:::10-08:::6
```

Thanks in advance.

***Update***
Here is what I attempted to code after I read the article that @Marcucciboy2 shared in his comments. I am, however, unable to retrieve that specific index of the matching key so that I could manipulate the value of they key.

```
For j = 0 To var2.Count - 1

                If dict.Exists(JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("author")("displayName") + ":" + Right(Left(JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("updated"), 10), 5)) Then

                    For k = 0 To dict.Count - 1
                        MsgBox dict.Keys(k) + " and its item is " + dict.Items(k)
                    Next k
                Else
                    dict.Add JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("author")("displayName") + ":" + Right(Left(JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("updated"), 10), 5), Left(JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("timeSpent"), 1)
                End If
Next j
```

Comment: Sigh. What is your code so far? Where are you stuck? You have not joined here yesterday, so you should know how the site works. If not, please take the [tour] again.

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#A_Real_World_Dictionary_Example

Comment: Thanks, Marcucciboy2. I am going thru the article.

Comment: If you start trying it don't be afraid to @ me after you edit in your attempt!

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - So, I did give it a go and this is what I ended up with. However, I still do not know how to retrieve the value of the matching key. FYI, I did early bind the dictionary object. I am unable to paste the code in the comment. I will attempt to "edit" my question so that I could show you what I have achieved so far.

Comment: I have no idea how to convert the strings you listed in the original question to the field names you gave as part of the JSONObj's

Comment: But, ostensibly, all that you should consider is that your "key" is `BKR:::10-03:::` and your value is `4` etc. Then when your key pops up a second time you can just add that to your running total value

Comment: Thank you. I was finally able to figure out how to achieve what I am looking for. Thanks to the link you shared. Is there a way I can accept a comment as an answer? Let me know.

Comment: Nope, but I'll definitely vote up any good work that you'd like to share - go ahead and answer your own problem!